# Show a list of files

Tags: android

I would like to show a list of files in the Android phone.

For example, i would like my app to be able to list all images stored in the phone, i dont want a gallery view, just a simple list.

I would also like to be able to show all the audio files

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standard/common media types such as Music, video and images in the internal memory, there are respective `ContentProviders` in the system that manage them. If you want to build list of such items you should consider querying respective `ContentProviders` (Google for `MediaStore` Provider).

However, if you want to build an exhaustive list of all the files in a particular directory, internal or external, you can use `File#listFiles()` API as was suggested by Fredley above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean on external storage. Read up on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), which will tell you the correct way to go about navigating the file-system.

> If you're using API Level 8 or
>   greater, use getExternalFilesDir() to
>   open a File that represents the
>   external storage directory where you
>   should save your files. This method
>   takes a type parameter that specifies
>   the type of subdirectory you want,
>   such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC and
>   DIRECTORY_RINGTONES (pass null to
>   receive the root of your application's
>   file directory). This method will
>   create the appropriate directory if
>   necessary. By specifying the type of
>   directory, you ensure that the
>   Android's media scanner will properly
>   categorize your files in the system
>   (for example, ringtones are identified
>   as ringtones and not music). If the
>   user uninstalls your application, this
>   directory and all its contents will be
>   deleted.
>
> If you're using API Level 7 or lower,
>   use getExternalStorageDirectory(), to
>   open a File representing the root of
>   the external storage.

Comment: that all seems to be about saving files? im just looking to display what is already there.

Comment: i have a file explorer, but this is somewhat messy for the user, and i would like to have all images found for them so they can just pick rather than navigate around the drives

Comment: The [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object you get back from this can be used to traverse the contents of the sd card.

Comment: It's not that hard once you've worked out how File objects work. Of particular interest is the [listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)) method.